# Highchart - Range Series - update dynamically

Tags: highcharts, range, series

I'm wondering how I can update range series dynamically.

Many thanks,

Comment: have you checked their documentation? https://www.highcharts.com/docs/index

Comment: It depends what do you want to achieve, but most of the dynamically updates you can do vis using those series features: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series

Comment: How can I update a range series? I mean series define with with x:, low: and high:.

Comment: Please reproduce your case on online editor which I could work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how range series are updated!

CurrentSeries.data[0].update([0,Timestamp1,Timestamp2]);

There is nothing about that in the doc Luciano!